# Cat has started drooling while sleeping?

Tags: cats, sleep

I adopted a new kitten and I found out that she have tapeworms so I gave her a  dewormer?

I noticed that she started drooling while sleeping and the smell isn't good. 
So is it normal to drool while sleep or is she sick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excessive salivation is a common side effect of deworming medication, but if it lasts more than three days you should contact your veterinarian.

Comment: Agreed - Praziquantel (the dewormer commonly used for tapeworms) has a very bitter disgusting taste. Most cats will drool initially after tasting this medication but it should stop soon. However I would say if it lasts more than 12 hours to contact your vet.